# TextInputEditText count the entered character as 2 characters

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin, android-textinputedittext

TextInputEditText has a limit on the maximum number of characters entered, for example 30. It is necessary that when you enter the @ character, it counts as 2, i.e. if you enter only @, then you can enter no more than 15 characters. How to implement such an algorithm?

Comment: Can you add examples to clarify what you mean? And any existing approaches that you might have tried?

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far? Share your thoughts / findings / code.

Comment: there is no algorithm required to do it. just set Text watcher in edit text and do the work manually.

Comment: can I get more details about using Text watcher?

Comment: The "@" character must be counted as two characters. The changes relate only to the input/editing processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found, function together with textChanges() RxJava

```
fun charDoubleLength(string:String, charDouble: Char, editText: EditText, maxLengthLine: Int){
        val charCount = string.filter { char ->
            char == charDouble
        }.count()
        val maxLengthEditText= maxLengthLine - charCount
        editText.filters =
            arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthEditText))
    }
```